# is there an R function to obtain the minimal depth distribution from a conditional random forest estimated with the party package?

Tags: r, random-forest

I ran a conditional random forest regression model using the `cforest` function from the `party` package because I have both categorical and continuous predictor variables that are correlated with each other, and a continuous outcome variable.

Here is my code to run the conditional random forest model, obtain out-of-bag estimates, and estimate the permutation variable importance.

```
# 1. fit the random forest
crf <- party::cforest(Y ~ ., data = df,
                      controls = party::cforest_unbiased(ntree = 10000, mtry = 7))

# 2. obtain out-of-bag estimates
pred_oob <- as.data.frame(caret::predict(crf, OOB = T, newdata = NULL))

# 3. estimate permutation variable importance
vi <- permimp::permimp(crf, condition = T, threshold = 0.5, nperm = 1000, OOB = T,
             mincriterion = 0)))
```

I would like to visualize the minimal depth distribution and calculate mean minimal depth similar to the output from the `RandomForestExplainer` package. However, the `RandomForestExplainer` package only takes in objects from the `randomForest` function in the `randomForest` package. It's not an option for me to use this function due to the nature of my data (described above).

I have been combing the internet and have not been able to find a solution. Can someone point me to a way to visualize the minimal depth distribution for all predictors and calculate the mean minimal depth?